# How to re-enable background transparency (Blender Render)?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

The 3d object below has a grey background. It should be transparent though (which is the default setting).
But somehow this is gone.

I'm using Blender Render.

Can you point me to the checkbox I need to click to get it transparent again?

[image]

Comment: Added an answer though please consider showing the entire Compositing node setup screenshot or attach your blender file (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop down under Properties/Render/Shading/Alpha. Although you seem to have a special compositing setup so it might be a different issue.

[image]